# Format date with SimpleDateFormat Java

Tags: java, android

I have a date string as

```
"Wed Jul 01 08:16:13 PDT 2015"
```

I am trying to parse it with this SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat valueDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

this way:

```
Date parsedDate1 = valueDateFormat.parse("Wed Jul 01 08:16:13 PDT 2015");
```

It is giving me parse error as:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jul 01 08:16:13 PDT 2015" (at offset 0)
```

How can I get a date in above simple date format from the string

Comment: please provide the code snippet

Comment: your Date formate and  simpledateformat formate are different.. that is why you are getting parseException....

Comment: @ravitejaKaveti but then how can I convert string to that format

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` construct takes a `String` for the template. Your template does not match the data you are trying to parse. You can learn more about how to form the correct template here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: try this in your SDF `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = originalFormat.parse("Wed Jul 01 08:16:13 PDT 2015");
String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date); 
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: this format worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't realy understand the consept of the SimpleDateFormat.

After you define the template with :

```
        SimpleDateFormat valueDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

The valueDateFormat could parse Date object acording to it, it not take just a String you have and convert it. it take Date object.

> [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your date string ("Wed Jul 01 08:16:13 PDT 2015") doesn't match your pattern ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

Write correct pattern which matches date string (first goes Day of week, than month in year, etc.)

Comment: I want to convert string to that format

Comment: For that, first you need to convert String to Date with correct format, and then convert Date to new String format

Answer (score 0):

For the formats like this I created a helper method:

```
public Date parseString(String date) {

    String value = date.replaceFirst("\\D+([^\\)]+).+", "$1");

    //Timezone could be either positive or negative
    String[] timeComponents = value.split("[\\-\\+]");

    long time = Long.parseLong(timeComponents[0]);
    int timeZoneOffset = Integer.valueOf(timeComponents[1]) * 36000; // (("0100" / 100) * 3600 * 1000)

    //If Timezone is negative
    if(value.indexOf("-") > 0){
        timeZoneOffset *= -1;
    }

    //Remember that time could be either positive or negative (ie: date before 1/1/1970)
    //time += timeZoneOffset;

    return new Date(time);
}
```

It returns date object from Date string so you can format your string like this:

```
Date date = parseString("Wed Jul 01 08:16:13 PDT 2015");
```

And after that you can easily format given date variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
public static void main(String[] a) 
{

  SimpleDateFormat valueDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM yy hh:mm:ss");
  try {
    Date parsedDate1 = valueDateFormat.parse("Wed Jul 01 08:16:13 PDT 2015");
    System.out.println(parsedDate1);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```